# Show that the following localization ring has one maximal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, localization

I was given the following question:

$R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $S$ contains all elements not divisible by $p$ (which is a given prime)

Prove that $S^{-1}R$ has only one maximal ideal

I tried assuming it has two and looking at one element in each that does not exist in the other but I didn't manage to come to any meaningful result so I'm pretty much stuck now, any thoughts on what to try next?

This subject is pretty new to me and I think I lack some intuition as to what the ring $S^{-1}R$ even is so any kind of explanation would be very much appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Hows is $S$ a subgroup of $\mathbb Z$? What is the group structure?

Comment: As I understand it if $p=2$ then $S$ contains all the odd integers. if $p=3$ then $S$ contains all integers not divisible by 3

Comment: Yes, but what is the operation that makes it a *subgroup*?

Comment: I meant  subset and wrote subgroup, fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S^{-1}R$ is the localization of $R$ at the prime ideal $p\mathbb{Z}$. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is an integral domain, we can describe $S^{-1}R$ as a subring of its field of fractions, i.e. $\mathbb{Q}$. In this case $S^{-1}R$ consists of all those rational numbers which can be written as $\frac{a}{s}$ where $a\in R,s\in S$ that is $a$ and $s$ are integers with $s$ not divisible by $p$.
Now for the actual question regarding the maximal ideals:
Show that the units in $S^{-1}R$ are precisely those elements in $S^{-1}R\setminus pS^{-1}R$. This then shows that $pS^{-1}R$ is the unique maximal ideal of $S^{-1}R$ (why?).

Comment: How should I show that $S^{-1}R \\ pS^{-1}R$ has only units?

Comment: Take an element $x\in S^{-1}R\setminus pS^{-1}R$. Since $x\in S^{-1}R$ we can write it as $x=\frac{a}{s}$ where $a,s\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $p\nmid s$. Since $x\notin pS^{-1}R$ we furthermore have $p\nmid a$. So what can we say about the rational number $x^{-1}=\frac{s}{a}$ in that case?

Comment: I think I have a notation problem, when you say $S^{-1}R\backslash pS^{-1}R$ do you mean the quotient ring or the set $S^{-1}R$ without the elements divisible by p?

Comment: I mean $\setminus$ as set difference, i.e. the latter thing you said.

Answer (score 1):

$S^{-1}R:=\{a/s:a\in R,p\not\mid s\}$ is a local ring with a unique maximal ideal $(p)$, since one may check that $S^{-1}R\setminus(p)$ is the group of units of $S^{-1}R$.

Suppose there is a prime ideal $0\ne\mathfrak p\subseteq (p)$. Let $a/s\in\mathfrak p$ be nonzero. Then $a/1\in\mathfrak p$. Let $a=up^k$ for $p\not\mid u$. Since $u/1\in S^{-1}A$ is a unit, we must have $p^k\in\mathfrak p$, so that since $\mathfrak p$ is prime, $p\in\mathfrak p$. Thus, in fact $\mathfrak p=(p)$.

Comment: I don't understand why if there is another maximal ideal it must be contained within $(p)$? What is they are completely different? or as I've tried have only one element different in each?

Comment: Because $(p)$ is the unique maximal ideal. (Note: $\mathfrak p$ is assumed only to be prime, not maximal)